# SP Upgrade - Joomla - cant find the values on the assets table

Tags: php, joomla, migration, upgrade

I just have migrated a website from `Joomla 1.0` to `Joomla 3.1` using `SP Upgrade`, and in the admin panel just appears the header and bottom part, without any content.

I believe the problem is the `assets` table don't have the right values.
But in `Root Asset` it looks ok.

```
{"core.login.site":{"6":1,"2":1},
"core.login.admin":{"6":1},
"core.login.offline":{"6":1},
"core.admin":{"8":1},
"core.manage":{"7":1},
"core.create":{"6":1,"3":1},
"core.delete":{"6":1},
"core.edit":{"6":1,"4":1},
"core.edit.state":{"6":1,"5":1},
"core.edit.own":{"6":1,"3":1}}
```

And I would like to know how to recover the admin panel for this website.

Answer (score 0):

Display has nothing to do with the assets table.

Go to 
site/administrator/index.php?option=com_users to check.  Look at the viewing access levels.
Make sure that super admin is in the special group.
Then make sure in the user manager that you are really a super admin.